# How to Identify This Pyspark Coding Issue - No viable alternative at input

Tags: azure, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, azure-synapse

Trying to run the following code in Azure Synapse pyspark and receive the parsing error, it doesn't seem like Synapse accept the double brackets, **anyone know how to fix it?**

```py
def curated_report(entity_name):
    sqlstr ="WITH Participant_Name \
    AS (SELECT \
    CASEID, \
    PARTICIPANTID, \
    LASTWRITTEN, \
    PARTICIPANT, \
    FIRSTNAME, \
    MIDDLENAME, \
    LASTNAME \
    FROM (SELECT \
    ab.CASEID, \
    ab.PARTICIPANTID, \
    ab.DYNAMICDATATYPE, \
    ab.DYNAMICEVIDENCEVALUE, \
    ab.LASTWRITTEN \
    FROM a.ev ab \
    INNER JOIN (SELECT \
    PARTICIPANTID, \
    MAX(LASTWRITTEN) AS MAXDATE \
    FROM a.bd \
    where TYPE in ( 'PDC001' ) \
    GROUP BY PARTICIPANTID) cd \
    ON ab.PARTICIPANTID = cd.PARTICIPANTID \
    AND ab.LASTWRITTEN = cd.MAXDATE \
    GROUP BY ab.CASEID, \
    ab.PARTICIPANTID, \
    ab.DYNAMICDATATYPE, \
    ab.DYNAMICEVIDENCEVALUE, \
    ab.LASTWRITTEN) AS SOURCE \
    PIVOT(max(DYNAMICEVIDENCEVALUE) \
    FOR DYNAMICDATATYPE IN (PARTICIPANT, \
    FIRSTNAME, \
    MIDDLENAME,\
    LASTNAME) \
    )AS RESULT) \         <----*this line seems to be causing error*
    SELECT* \
    FROM PARTICIPANT_NAME"
    df = spark.sql(sqlstr)
    return df


*solved.
```

Comment: Did you try this? `AS [RESULT])`, putting the alias `result` inside a square bracket?

Comment: Is it running in SparkSQL with out any error?

Comment: I did try it, and it didn't work but figured out another way to do this without pivoting the table. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ParseException:
> no viable alternative at input 'WITH Participant_Name     AS (SELECT   ...

Remove `as RESULT` from the query. For CTE table, it is sufficient to give with CTE table name.

*Error Screenshot*
I tried to repro this with similar script and got the same error.
[image]

- In order to avoid this error, I removed the alias name  `as Result` from the Query and it is executed successfully.

**Corrected Code**

```py
sqlstr ="WITH Participant_Name \
    AS (SELECT \
    CASEID, \
    PARTICIPANTID, \
    LASTWRITTEN, \
    PARTICIPANT, \
    FIRSTNAME, \
    MIDDLENAME, \
    LASTNAME \
    FROM (SELECT \
    ab.CASEID, \
    ab.PARTICIPANTID, \
    ab.DYNAMICDATATYPE, \
    ab.DYNAMICEVIDENCEVALUE, \
    ab.LASTWRITTEN \
    FROM enhanced.BDMCASEEVIDENCE ab \
    INNER JOIN (SELECT \
    PARTICIPANTID, \
    MAX(LASTWRITTEN) AS MAXDATE \
    FROM enhanced.BDMCASEEVIDENCE \
    where EVIDENCETYPE in ( 'PDC0000258' ) \
    GROUP BY PARTICIPANTID) cd \
    ON ab.PARTICIPANTID = cd.PARTICIPANTID \
    AND ab.LASTWRITTEN = cd.MAXDATE \
    GROUP BY ab.CASEID, \
    ab.PARTICIPANTID, \
    ab.DYNAMICDATATYPE, \
    ab.DYNAMICEVIDENCEVALUE, \
    ab.LASTWRITTEN) AS SOURCE \
    PIVOT(max(DYNAMICEVIDENCEVALUE) \
    FOR DYNAMICDATATYPE IN ('PARTICIPANT', \
    'FIRSTNAME', \
    'MIDDLENAME',\
    'LASTNAME') \
    )) \         
    SELECT* \
    FROM PARTICIPANT_NAME"
    df = spark.sql(sqlstr)
```